# web based native app

Tags: javascript, desktop

How does one create a native app (windows, mac, or linux) that has the similar characteristics of a web app? I'm looking at 'dynamic' updates every time the app is launched by getting the code to run elsewhere (similar to rich web apps with javascript). It must retain the native gui however, with the behaviors/conventions expected in the OS it is created for.

Comment: You can do HTTP requests (or even better for desktop apps: socket communications) in any language out there. You can build native apps in many languages (C, C++, I guess C# could be called "native", Python has bindings for "nativeness", ...)

Comment: What "similar characteristics of a web app" do you want? What you've described ("native gui") doesn't sound like a web app at all.

Comment: Are we just talking about an auto-updating application?

Comment: Auto updating, yes, that's definitely a part of it. I'm looking for something such that everytime I open the app, I have the latest code downloaded over the network - much like how I go to a website, and I have the latest of everything. Moreover, the app is revealed/downloaded on a per click basis - much like how I am led by links on a website.

Answer (score 1):

Because native apps can use most of the system hardware or software, you can just wrap the web app in something like phone gap and then the user wouldn't know the difference. We've made one for our website using jQuery mobile and Phonegap for Android and iPhone.

For more information on how to develop the solution I was talking about (this is what we use):
http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/developing-for-the-iphone-and-ipad-by-runing-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-on-a-pc/